# What's the most distant radio message we could detect with today's radio telescopes, if the message is initially broadcasted in all directions?

Tags: aliens

An additional assumption is that broadcasting the message may require using a medium-sized star, like the Sun, for an hour, by e.g. Dysoning it.

I don't know enough to answer the question myself. If the question needs more details filled in to be well-formed, you can make additional assumptions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: VTC: Needs details. Modern radio telescopes could detect a signal from the edge of known space if they know exactly where to look and the signal's broadcast strength is great enough. You don't tell us what your limits, conditions, and restrictions are (a requirement for all Qs, see the [help/on-topic]). "Dyson" refers to a number of megastructures with a variety of capabilities. "Medium-sized star" is an almost meaningless statement when we need to know the specific broadcast power. Frankly, it would be better to tell us the distance and ask what broadcast power is needed.

Comment: The Three Body Problem - Chinese sci-fi novel.

Comment: Define 'detect'. Does the message have to be meaningful (i.e., enough resolution in the signal when it gets to Earth to extract meaningful data) or does it just have to be detected as a non-natural signal, even though there is no longer enough resolution to extract meaning? In the good ol' days, when television was broadcast 'over the air', one could pick up a distant station, but the 'picture' was barely discernable from the noise. You knew it was a station that was being broadcast, but had no idea of what was being broadcast.

Answer (score 2):

### With a lot of luck, about 30 million light-years

Quite obviously, this is exactly the same thing as how far away is the farthest Sun-sized star which we can observe.

The farthest star ever observed is [Earendel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHL0137-LS), about 28 billion light-years away. Earendel is about a million times more luminous than the Sun, therefore for a star about as luminous as the Sun we need to divide that distance by one thousand.

Note that Earendel is observable only because of luck; there is a galaxy cluster between it and us, which serves as a gigantic gravitational lens.

In the absence of such amount of good luck, the best we hope to observe a star about as luminous as the Sun is for it to be in the Milky Way, and not in an unfavourable position. (We cannot see through the center of the galaxy. There is stuff in between which extinguishes the light.) So, about 100,000 light years.

Answer (score 0):

## Several billion light years away

Most of the universe is empty, so you don't need to send messages to it. They can target pulses of energy at clumps of galaxies or galaxies, and use galaxies as lenses to focus their light at extremely distance targets. The most powerful telescopes earth has can see stars around 10 million light years away with no aid, and as mentioned in another comment with careful aid Earendel can be seen 28 billion light years away.

It's hard to predict exactly how far your message would go, but an extremely advanced alien species who can build a dyson sphere is probably pretty good at optimizing the vast amount of energy they use and hitting every galaxy.

Comment: Unfortunately, even though most of the universe is empty, *nowhere* near enough of it is. The sun outputs ~$3.8×10^{26} \text{W}$.  I've seen estimates of $5*10^{17}$ stars within 1 billion lightyears of us. If we're sending said power in a 1AU radius of each star, that's about $10\text{fW}/\text{m}^2$. Or about 1 billionth of the CMB: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28solar+luminosity+%2F+%28500000+trillion+*+pi+*+1au+*+1au%29%29+%2F+%28%28cmb+temperature%5E4%29+*+stefan-boltzmann+constant%29)

Comment: Even if you radiated at each star for 1 second / 1 year you'd still radiate at only ~10% of the CMB background.

Comment: And that's assuming you can predict the locations of everything within <<1AU in a billion years time... which is not possible. (N-body dynamics are chaotic, rather famously.)

Comment: Now that I look at it, that figure may be off. I suspect it's actually of the observable universe, not 1B lightyear radius.